# Передать переменную в javascript файл

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

В приложении написаном express можно передать переменную в шаблон так:

```
router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    var test = 9;
    res.render('main/login', {
        testVar: test
    });
});
```

А как передать переменную в javascript файл?

Comment: Откуда вы хотите передавать переменные? И в какой именно js файл?

Comment: Передать в js файл на клиенте. В шаблонизаторе ejs, переменную я вывожу так: <%= testVar %> а как получить эту переменную в js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача передачи конфигурационных параметров из серверного приложения клиентскому возникает регулярно. В большинстве случаев, правильнее всего сделать некую функцию, инициализирующую клиентское приложение, а в процессе рендеринга страницы передавать этой функции объект с конфигурационными параметрами.

Что касается EJS, то он поддерживает синтаксис `<%- data %>`, который позволяет выключать автоэскейпирование. Вместе с `JSON.stringify` это полноностью решает проблему передачи данных в клиентское приложение.

Например, ваш шаблон может иметь вид:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Этот код стоит вынести в отдельный файл.
            var initApp = function(options) {
                // ... Логика инициализации клиентского приложения.
                console.log(options.foo);
                console.log(options.bar);
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Инициализируем клиентское приложение с данными, переданными
            // из серверного приложения.
            initApp(<%- appConfigs %>);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Здесь могла быть ваша разметка -->
    </body>
</html>
```

А код, занимающийся отрисовкой, может иметь вид:

```
var ejs = require('ejs'),
    template = '...';

var appConfigs = {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz'
};

ejs.render(template, {
    title: 'An awesome page!',
    appConfigs: JSON.stringify(appConfigs)
});
```